# 2 ISP's into one network

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, remote, isp

So the situation I've gotten myself into is this:

I have a client with a rural property that we've done some automation and networking work for as part of his new home build. The problem we had, is in order to support the client best we need remote access to the site.

His ISP? Xplornet (I don't need to say much more)

There was another building on this property with a different ISP that had static public facing IP's available, they have small packages only so we figured for remote access it would be perfect for the little traffic required. Opted to use the dual wan functionality of the router we have already in place, only to find out it was a fail-over function only.

So I would like to employ a little help with the finer details in this idea of mine to solve our problem.

The first router will maintain the xplornet connection, DHCP, and be used as the main connection for streaming/surfing internet related tasks. I've figured out with some google-fu that as long as I don't change the gateway, all the local user traffic should remain through this router. Right?

I want to deploy a second router and use the ISP with the static. Static the router, turn off DHCP, enable the port forwarding rules I need, and turn on an OpenVPN client on this router. Use this connection strictly for remote access into the network.

My main concern only with this plan is, do I need to change the gateway on any of the automation equipment I wish to remote into. (ie. phone apps that require direct connection to it, and not through the VPN)

Edit: clarification of OpenVPN capable router is in the environment. Not a seperate server.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal equipment will need to know how to route packets back to the OpenVPN originating client, otherwise it will send everything "not on the LAN" to the primar router.

If the default route is via the primary router, perhaps it can be given a static route for the OpenVPN subnet on the secondary router. Failing that, you'll need to put explicit routes for the OpenVPN on every device on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add a static route on the main router so traffic from clients  targeted at the remote side of the VPN endpoint are rerouted to the VPN router.

That said, if its an option, I would handle this differently.  I would set the client up with a VPN client rather then a server, and integrate the VPN client into the router (or put the whole network behind a second VPN capable router).  In this way the VPN client does not need a static IP address and there are no routing hacks or changes.  (It does, however, limit remote access to people who can connect to the VPN server)